# jQuery Cell Referencing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, reference

This code creates a seating layout. The classes determine the cost of seats and the jquery objects contain the layout, and the data for me to determine classes.

```
var jsondata = {
"who": "RSNO",
    "what": "An American Festival",
    "when": "2013-02-08 19:30",
    "where": "User Hall - Main Auditorium",
    "seats": ["00000000000000000011111111111111000000000000000000", "0000000000000001111111111111111aaa0000000000000000", "00000000000000aa111111111111111aaaaa00000000000000", "00000000000001111111111111111111111111000000000000", "000000000aa00aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1100aa000000000", "00000001111001111111111111111111111100111100000000", "00000aaaaaa0011aaaaaaaaa11111111aaa1100aaaaaa00000", "00001111111001111111111111111111111100111111100000", "000aaaaaaa110011111111111111111111110011aaaaaaa000", "00111111111100111111111111111111111001111111111000", "00aaaaa1111110011111111111111111111001111aaaaaaa00", "11111111111100111111111111111111111001111111111110", "0aaaaaaaaaaaa001111111111111111111100aaaaaaaaaaaa0", "01111111111110011111111111111111110011111111111100", "00000000000000001111111111111111110000000000000000", "01111111111111001111111111111111100111111111111100", "01111111111111001111111111111111110011111111111110", "01111111111111001111111111111111100111111111111100", "00a11111111111100111111111111111100111111111111a00", "00111111111111100111111111111111001111111111111000", "00011111111111110011111111111111001111111111111000", "00111111111111100111111111111111001111111111111000", "00011111111111110011111111111111001111111111111000", "00011111111111110011111111111110011111111111110000", "0000000111a111111001111a1111a110011111111110000000", "00000000111111110011111111111110011111111000000000", "00000000001111111001111111111110011111110000000000", "00000000000000111001111111111100111000000000000000"],
    "rows": ["DD", "CC", "BB", "AA", "Z", "Y", "X", "W", "V", "U", "T", "S", "R", "Q", "xx", "P", "N", "M", "L", "K", "J", "H", "G", "F", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A"],
    "seatPrice": ["                  00000000000000                  ", "               0000000000000000000                ", "              0000000000000000000000              ", "             0000000000000000000000000            ", "         00  000000000000000000000000  00         ", "       0000  00000000000000000000000  0000        ", "     000000  000000000000000000000000  000000     ", "    0000000  00000000000000000000000  0000000     ", "   000000000  0000000000000000000000  000000000   ", "  0000000000  000000000000000000000  0000000000   ", "  00000000000  00000000000000000000  00000000000  ", "000000000000  000000000000000000000  000000000000 ", " 000000000000  00000000000000000000  000000000000 ", " 000000000000  0000000000000000000  000000000000  ", "                000000000000000000                ", " 0000000000000  00000000000000000  0000000000000  ", " 0000000000000  000000000000000000  0000000000000 ", " 0000000000000  00000000000000000  0000000000000  ", "  0000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000  ", "  0000000000000  000000000000000  0000000000000   ", "   0000000000000  00000000000000  0000000000000   ", "  0000000000000  000000000000000  0000000000000   ", "   0000000000000  00000000000000  0000000000000   ", "   0000000000000  0011111111100  0000000000000    ", "       0000000000  111111111111  0000000000       ", "        00000000  1111111111111  00000000         ", "          0000000  111111111111  0000000          ", "              000  00000000000  000               "],
    "priceLookup": [10, 20]
};

var counter = 0;
var tbl_body = "";
var print = "";

$.each(jsondata.seats, function (j, d) {
var tbl_row = "";
$.each(this, function (k, v) {
    var seatPrice = jsondata.seatPrice[j][k];            
        if (v == "1" || v == "a") {
            counter++;
        }

        if (v == 0) {
            print = " ";
        } else {
            print = v;
        }
        var seatPriceClass = '';
        if (seatPrice == "0") {
            seatPriceClass = "p";
        } else if (seatPrice == "1") {
            seatPriceClass = "n";
        } else {
            seatPriceClass = "none";
        }
        if (v == "a") {
            seatPriceClass = "x";
        }


        tbl_row += "<td class=" + seatPriceClass + " id=" + counter + ">" + print + "</td>";

    });

    tbl_body += "<tr>" + tbl_row + "</tr>";
    counter = 0;

});
$("#plan").html(tbl_body);
```

In the two arrays, the table is created populated to create the layout. The counter starts counting a row when it finds a seat (ie, seats are 1, no seats are 0, so when it hits a 1 it begins to count until the end of the row). This is all correct and working thus far, except I need to use the `rows` object within the JSON file to create a row reference that I can append to the counter data to give the cell an id (ie c7), which I can then use as a seat reference.

I've tried this function nested, but it doesn't work, or throw errors

```
 $.each(function(j, g){
    var row_id =jsondata.rows[j][g];
     });
```

How would I get this function, or something similar to work in my arrays?

Comment: May be your question is not complete but I am suspicious of `jsondata.seatPrice[j][k]; ` , As I see the seatPrice is single dimension array but you are treating it as two-dimensional. Might be I am missing sth ?

Comment: @sakhunzai `seatPrice` is an array running concurrently with `seats` so that j is an incremented value and k is the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `jsondata.rows[j]`

```
tbl_row += "<td class=" + seatPriceClass + " id=" + jsondata.rows[j] + counter + ">" + print + "</td>";
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. You need to adjust the logic a little bit though, to generate ids **ONLY** to real seats. Because as of right now it generates duplicate ids and that makes markup invalid.